# IE caching behaviour: response 304 followed by 200's on same resource?

Tags: http, amazon-s3, browser-cache

I'm puzzled by the fact that I'm requesting a video file from our S3 bucket that has max-age set to 1 year. I sometimes get a 304, but far more often these are followed by multiple 200 responses. I'm trying to get this right in IE11.

[image]

Here are the request and response of the 304:

[image]

[image]

I also took snapshots of these requests (at another moment) with Charles proxy:

[image]

[image]

And here are the request and response of the 200:

[image]

[image]

And here are the request and response as seen from Charles proxy:

[image]

[image]

The requests are triggered by a  DOM element that is first being added (that seems to be the 304) and then playback is periodically started again from the beginning in Javascript (those seem to be the 200's).

So the question is: what have I possibly missed in settings or anything that is preventing resources like this from being cached?

Thanks.

P.S.

1. Just to be clear: "Always refresh from server" is OFF
2. I also see that the 200 responses are not like Google's "200 (from cache)", since the total download volume keeps increasing with every video load.

Comment: Interesting issue here. First of all let's decide where then issue is. From looking at the header the browser is sending all the correct headers and the issue is in the server itself. The server here is seeing you new file in the case of 200 OK hence the file size change and serving the new file using 200 OK is the expected behaviour . but what is strange here is why the server sending the new file with the same old etag !!!. I think the web interface you use is hiding some headers I would suggest redo the test while running Charles proxy or wireshark to see if there is any difference

Comment: @Hani thank you for looking at this with me. I added new header snapshots made with Charles proxy, but I don't really see any difference. The only thing I do see with the 304 response, is that the request is made with an "If-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Match" header. I guess those enable the server to return the 304, but then the question is why IE does not send those headers when replaying the video. BTW, the server is Amazon S3. Any further ideas?

Comment: the snapshot on charles proxy when we get 200 OK does not have "If-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Match" headers. this mean the client here didnt want to get the cached version and getting 200 OK in this case is normal .but what makes me wonder is why in your first snapshot without charles proxy those headers where present on the request that got the 200OK. now if we can confirm that we only get 200 OK for first request and any subsequent request without the modified header we can at least conclude the issue is client side here and in this case we will need your js code that reload the resource

Comment: In your JavaScript request to get the file can you add headers manually. Like using setRequestHeader and set if modified since in the is request buy that way you force it to use the cache

Comment: @Hani Thanks for sticking with me! First, it looks like I pasted in the wrong 200-request screen shot from IE... it actually does NOT contain the "If-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Match" tags. So the fact that the browser does not do that, maybe has something to do with this...? What I'm doing in JS is first adding a <video> element to the DOM, which triggers the 304-request-response. Then we're periodically restarting the video in JS, we see the 200-request-responses. I've also tried removing the <video> element and re-adding it, but that also leads to the 200-request-responses. :( Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the html part that first load the element (the one that calls load() method) . also if possible show me the js part the do the playback specially what call you use to restart the video. and finally when you restart the video do you reload anything else on the page ? as that may cause the behavour

Comment: @Hani, there's quite a bit going on in the original source code, but I'll try to prune it down to the bare essentials. I'll get back to you -hopefully- tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hani, I spent quite some time trying to reproduce the exact scenario where this was going wrong. I finally found that it had to do with the custom domain names we were using. Although I have NO idea what the root cause is, we did find a workaround for this. See my answer below. Thank you very much for your time and helping hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what caused this strange caching behaviour. For one it was only happening in Internet Explorer only (I tested version 11 only). Before I explain, a little bit of background...

Our main application runs on a main domain, let's call it www.foo.com. Ajax requests are done to different application instances on ajax.foo.com. We have resellers of our service run the main domain under their own domain name, e.g. www.bar.com. They still use the regular Ajax domain ajax.foo.com (not sure if this is related, but I thought it might be worth mentioning).

What I found is that when the application starts from the main domain www.foo.bar, all videos coming from S3 are cached correctly. But as soon as we run the main application from the reseller domain, caching does not happen anymore. See the screenshots below.

I'm still utterly puzzled with the dependency of S3 asset caching on the main domain name. We have not found any root cause for this. So we decided to go for a workaround that works for us: the reseller starts the application by simply opening a web page that contains an iframe that starts the actual application on the regular main domain www.foo.com on which caching works fine. This solves our problem, although I'm left with a bad taste that we did not find and solve the actual cause.

**Caching behavior on the reseller domain**

Note all the extra requests with a response 200 and the additional downloaded volume.

[image]

**Caching behavior on the main domain**

Note the lack of any additional requests for the resources over time

[image]

Comment: in your IE settings can you set this Access data sources across domains to enabled and see if it has any affect in caching ?

Comment: I switched this setting to "enabled", but it still exhibited the same behaviour where it does not seem to cache these files from S3. :( Thanks for the suggestion, though. Would still love to find the root cause...